# If you take IE out of the picture what additional JavaScript functionality is available in the other browsers?

Tags: javascript

I'm just talking about JavaScript here, not CSS or implementation of the DOM.

I know getters and setters are now available in the latest release of all major browsers except IE. What other JavaScript features are available cross-browser if we have the latest versions of the other browsers and forget about IE for a minute?

Answer (score 2):

With Gecko-engined browsers, you get:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.8

In terms of other browsers implementing these features, I'm only aware of Webkit implementing [Array Extras](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6#Array_extras), but it's actually quite easy to [monkeypatch support for those in all browsers](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/05/17.53.19/) since they're just additional methods.

Gecko, Opera and Webkit also support the [`canvas` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial), which although being a new HTML element, is used via JavaScript, so I'm not sure if that fits your criteria. Having said that, there are [independent efforts underway](http://blog.vlad1.com/2008/07/30/no-browser-left-behind/) to bring it to IE.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you visit [www.quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org) for a lot of detailed comparisons of different browsers/versions.

Comment: Quirksmode only shows information regarding HTML/CSS/DOM/Events, I'm talking about JavaScript language features.

Answer (score 0):

XML APIs:

- [DOMParser](http://www.xulplanet.com/references/objref/DOMParser.html) object
- [XMLSerializer](http://www.xulplanet.com/references/objref/XMLSerializer.html) object
- [XSLTProcessor](http://www.xulplanet.com/references/objref/XSLTProcessor.html) object
- [DOM XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html) implementation

Although these are not "JavaScript functionality", rather DOM APIs